# Declare multiple values in ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm wondering how I can declare multiple values within a single ng-init, without having to create some weird hash, that then I need to always access specifically.

so basically I would like

```
<div ng-init="a = 1, b = 2">{{a}}</div>
```

and I'm saying that I would like to avoid having to do

```
<div ng-init="unecessary_bs = {a: 1, b: 2}">{{unecessary_bs.a}}</div>
```

However the reasonable :

```
<div ng-init="a = 1, b = 2">{{a}}</div>
```

doesn't seem to work.

Anticipated Thanks

Comment: `"a = 1, b = 2"` wouldn't be reasonable since its javascript, and semicolons are the ones who separate statements, but the idea holds the same

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Use a function, way more readable:

```
ng-init="init()"
```

And:

```
$scope.init = function() {
    $scope.a = 1;
    $scope.b = 2;
}
```

Or, if you must, separate inline variables with a semi-colon:

```
ng-init="a = 1; b = 2"
```

Comment: this will not work for ng-repeat, as it has its own scope see http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13212/

Comment: @Toolkit use dot notation (controllerAs syntax) to reference a function outside the isolate scope of an ng-repeat. pass the predefined $index var of an ng-repeat to a function called from the view.

Comment: From which side the evaluation starts? for example if I want to use a variable in another statement, How should I write my statement? ex: ng-init="a=12;b=1+a" or init="b=1+a;a=12;"? does it evaluates from left as javascript?

Comment: @Пуя - I would assume so. You can test it: `ng-init="c = a + b; a = 1; b = 2"` and see what the result of `c` is - Best guess, it goes left to right.

Answer (score 40):

Sometimes its not ideal to put the variables in a function.
For example your backend is in express and you are rendering a file using jade.

With Express.js you can send local variables to the html.
Angular can accept these variables with

```
ng-init=""
```

Using ";" one can have multiple variables

Example

```
ng-init=" hello='world'; john='doe' "
```

Answer (score 8):

I prefer wrap with object init variable:

```
<div ng-init="initObject = {initParam: 'initParamValue', anotherOne: 'value'}"></div>
```

Comment: This is genius!

Answer (score 3):

```
 <div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-init='initTodo = init(todo)'>
        <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}} |
                               and todo.text via init:{{initTodo}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

**AND**

```
  var modulse = angular.module("app",[]);

  modulse.controller("TodoCtrl", function ($scope)  {

            $scope.todos = [ {text:'todo1'}, {text:'todo2'}]; 

            $scope.init = function (todo) {  return todo.text; };

  });
```